# Numerical value of Derivative of Dirichlet L function at some particular points

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, number-theory, numerical-value

I want to find the numerical value for the derivative of Dirichlet L function to compare with an another formula. However I am not able to obtain any numerical values. I tried to use

```
f[s_]= DirichletL[5,2,s]
f'[3]
```

But this simply returns  `DirichletL^(0,0,1)[5,2,3]`.
If I use `N[f'[3]]` this gives: `DirichletL:: Positive integer expected at position 1 in DirichletL[5.,2.,2.].`

Can someone please help me out with this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `N` it converts **all** numeric values to reals. The first two arguments to `DirichletL` must remain integer.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

D[DirichletL[5, 2, s], s] /. s -> 3.

(* 0.0150711 - 0.0479906 I *)

Derivative[0, 0, 1][DirichletL][5, 2, 3.]

(* 0.0150711 - 0.0479906 I *)

f[s_] := DirichletL[5, 2, s]

f'[3.]

(* 0.0150711 - 0.0479906 I *)
```

Comment: Well this really helped, but I am wondering that in the first code that you have written why do we need to write "3." And why is there a problem if we write "3" only?

Comment: When you enter an **exact** number (e.g. `3`), you are asking for an **exact** result. The only exact representation for the argument `3` is the unevaluated form. Just like if you enter `Sin[3]`. By entering `3.` you are indicating that a numeric approximation is desired.